# How to use conditionals without attaching it to an element?

Tags: vue.js

In vue, we have got directives v-if which needs to be attached to element.

Is there a way to use conditionals without attaching them to anything like the mustachejs way?

I am looping through an array of words and it is adding div's in every word which is annoying

Here is my template

```
<div v-for="(str, index) in reference" :key="index">
  <div v-if="patternIncluded(str)">
    <input type="text" v-model="remarks[index]">
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    {{str}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I would be nice if i could do it like this:|

```
{{if true}}
something goes here
{{else}}
other thing goes here
{{\if}}
```

Comment: You'd probably use a ternary in an expression, but we probably need to see some code to help you

Comment: @GeorgeJempty i have updated my question

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want to achieve, that's why I'm posting this as an comment: http://jsfiddle.net/edsLrjmu/1/ (Example contains two possible solutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code but using the **< template >** tag

```
<template v-if="patternIncluded(str)">
    <input type="text" v-model="remarks[index]">
</template>
<template v-else>
    {{str}}
</template>
```

Here is a example from the official Vue documentation:

```
<template v-if="loginType === 'username'">
  <label>Username</label>
  <input placeholder="Enter your username">
</template>
<template v-else>
  <label>Email</label>
  <input placeholder="Enter your email address">
</template>
```

More informations: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Controlling-Reusable-Elements-with-key

You can also use a [Method](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) and use normal Javascript into the **< script >** at the bottom of your file

Hope this helped, cheers

Comment: wrapping it inside a template too creates a div

Comment: @Raaz you should replace the div with the v-if with the template:
I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

you could use the 'template' like so:

```
<template v-if=patternIncluded(str)>
      //code
</template

<template v-else>
      //code
</template>
```

**UPDATE** so like this

```
<div-for="(str, index) in reference" :key="index">
    <template v-if="patternIncluded(str)">
        <input type="text" v-model="remarks[index]">
   </template>
   <template v-else>
        {{str}}
   </template>
</div>
```